# VSCode で Django のデバッグを行う際にモジュールを import できない

Tags: python, django, vscode

**解決したいこと**
visual studio codeでデバッグ開始をすると、
views.pyの「from .forms import........」
のforms.pyファイルが読み込まれずに、止まってしまい、下記のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

**エラー内容**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main.forms'; 'main' is not a package
```

補足
ターミナル上からpython manage.py runserverをした際にはエラーは発生しません。

**問題の可能性**

デバッグ機能では相対パスを読み込めないのが原因なのでしょうか？
色々調べたのですが、設定が上手くいきません。
ご教授いただけると、幸いです。

**開発環境**
pyenv 1.2.4-8-g43235c2
virtualenv --version 16.0.0
（自分がpyenvとvirtualenvのどちらを使用しているか不明）
ターミナルでデスクトップ上に移動し、source myvenv/bin/activateというコマンドで仮想環境に入っています。
(myvenvはデスクトップ上にあるフォルダです。）
Django2.0.2
python 3.6.5
visual studio code 1.25.1 (1.25.1)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/164228

Answer (score 0):

回答がついていないので、経験から書かせていただきます。

1.メニューの「ファイル」 -> 「フォルダーを開く」で、対象のDjangoプロジェクトディレクトリを開く。
2.デバッグ環境の選択リストを「Python: Django」に変更する。

これでデバッグ実行を試していただくとどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`forms.py`や`views.py`と同一のディレクトリに`__init__.py`が存在しないため、パッケージとして読み込めていないかと推察されます。
中身は空で良いので、呼び出したいpythonモジュールと同じディレクトリに`__init__.py`を新規作成すれば解決できると考えます。

それでも解決しない場合は一度、ディレクトリの構造をご質問に追記いただけますと幸いです。